# Restricting template type to enum class

Tags: c++, templates, enums

The function `get_from_string` below basically casts a `string` to a variable by creating a `stringstream` from the `string` and writing that to (a pointer of) the variable. Afterwards, it returns whether that was successful or not. If the variable is an `enum class`, it goes a little detour over the `enum class`' `underlying_type` and uses a `static_cast` to achieve the same effect.

The code below works perfectly, but I can't manage to get rid of the two `get_from_string_helper_struct`s. Can I solve this without any helper structs and only with functions?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

template <typename T, typename U = std::underlying_type_t<T>>
U to_underlying(T v) {
  return static_cast<U>(v);
}

template <typename T, typename U = std::underlying_type_t<T>>
bool get_enum_from_string(T *target, const std::string &input) {
  U n;
  bool valid_input = static_cast<bool>(std::istringstream(input) >> n);
  *target = static_cast<T>(n);
  return valid_input;
}

template <typename T>
bool get_non_enum_from_string(T *target, const std::string &input) {
  T n;
  bool valid_input = static_cast<bool>(std::istringstream(input) >> n);
  *target = n;
  return valid_input;
}

template <typename T, class Enable = void>
struct get_from_string_helper_struct {
  bool get(T *target, const std::string &input) {
    return get_non_enum_from_string(target, input);
  }
};

template <typename T>
struct get_from_string_helper_struct<
    T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value>::type> {
  bool get(T *target, const std::string &input) {
    return get_enum_from_string(target, input);
  }
};

template <typename T>
bool get_from_string(T *target, const std::string &input) {
  return get_from_string_helper_struct<T>().get(target, input);
}

enum class foo : uint8_t {
  foo1 = 1,
  foo2 = 2
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  bool valid = false;

  foo bar1;
  valid = get_from_string(&bar1, "1");
  std::cout << to_underlying(bar1) << (valid ? " True" : " False") << std::endl;

  uint8_t bar2;
  valid = get_from_string(&bar2, "1");
  std::cout << bar2 << (valid ? " True" : " False") << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1 True
1 True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With C++17, you might do:

```
template <typename T>
bool get_from_string(T *target, const std::string &input) {
    if constexpr (std::is_enum_v<T>) {
        std::underlying_type_t<T> value{};
        auto res = get_from_string(&value, input);
        *target = static_cast<T>(value);
        return res;
    } else {
        return static_cast<bool>(std::istringstream(input) >> *target);
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/307ce29c7543fb95).

Comment: With this solution the behavior differs for enum and non enum types. An enum type will have a default initialized value assigned if reading a proper enum value from the string fails while this is not the case for other types.

Comment: @Pixelchemist: Already the case in OP code.We can still handle the case specifically. Don't know expected behavior in case of failure.On my side, I would change signature to return `std::optional<T>`.

Comment: I'd argue that it is not the case in OP code since `get_non_enum_from_string` and `get_enum_from_string` differ only in the definition of `n` and the `static_cast` of the assignment. (I worry about about UB in OPs code because of the assignment of the uninitialized value in case of a failing `operator>>` though.)

Answer (score 2):

Without C++17 I tend to think that a solution with helper types is cleaner than multiple functions:

```
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <sstream>

template<class T, class U = typename std::conditional<std::is_enum<T>::value, void, T>::type>
struct streamtype { using type = T; };

template<class T>
struct streamtype<T, void> { using type = typename std::underlying_type<T>::type; };

template <typename T>
bool get_from_string(T& target, std::string const& input) 
{
    typename streamtype<T>::type n{};
    bool valid_input = static_cast<bool>(std::istringstream(input) >> n);
    target = static_cast<T>(n);
    return valid_input;
}
```

With C++17 you might go for:

```
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <sstream>

template <class T, class U = T>
bool get_from_string_impl(T& target, std::string const& input) 
{
    U n{};
    bool valid_input = static_cast<bool>(std::istringstream(input) >> n);
    target = static_cast<T>(n);
    return valid_input;
}

template <class T>
bool get_from_string(T& target, std::string const& input) 
{
    if constexpr (std::is_enum_v<T>) 
        return get_from_string_impl<T, typename std::underlying_type<T>::type>(target, input);
    else 
        return get_from_string_impl<T>(target, input);
}
```

Comment: There is an extra `_impl` at the end of second function in second example.

Answer (score 1):

Have two `get_from_string_impl` functions, one takes `true_type is_enum`, the other `false_type`.

```
template <typename T>
bool get_from_string_impl(std::true_type is_enum, T *target, const std::string &input) {
  using U = std::underlying_type_t<T>;
  U n;
  bool valid_input = static_cast<bool>(std::istringstream(input) >> n);
  *target = static_cast<T>(n);
  return valid_input;
}

template <typename T>
bool get_from_string_impl(std::false_type is_enum, T *target, const std::string &input) {
  T n;
  bool valid_input = static_cast<bool>(std::istringstream(input) >> n);
  *target = n;
  return valid_input;
}
template <typename T>
bool get_from_string(T *target, const std::string &input) {
  return get_from_string_impl(std::is_enum_t<T>{}, target, input);
}
```

---

Alternatively, write dispatch:

```
template<class Left, class Right>
Left dispatch(std::true_type, Left left, Right ){ return left; }
template<class Left, class Right>
Right dispatch(std::false_type, Left, Right right ){ return right; }
```

now you can

```
dispatch(
  std::is_enum_t<Foo>{},
  [&](auto& x){ /* x is an enum */ },
  [&](auto& x){ /* x is not an enum */ }
)(foo);
```

note that passing foo is required, as foo directly captured is both an enum and not, while foo passed through is an enum or not.

```
template <typename T>
bool get_from_string(T *target, const std::string &input) {
  return dispatch( std::is_enum_t<T>(),
    [&](auto* enum_target) {
      return get_enum_from_string(enum_target, input);
    },
    [&](auto* notenum_target) {
      return get_non_enum_from_string(notenum_target, input);
    }
  )(target);
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a minimal working example that implements `get_from_string` with the signature above?

Answer (score 1):

What is the problem with the trivial alternative that use `std::enable_if` in an optional parameter?

```
template <typename T, 
    typename U = std::underlying_type_t<T>
    typename V = typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value>::type>
bool get_from_string(T *target, const std::string &input) {
    U n;
    bool valid_input = static_cast<bool>(std::istringstream(input) >> n);
    *target = static_cast<T>(n);
    return valid_input;
}

template <typename T, 
    typename V = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_enum<T>::value>::type>
bool get_from_string(T *target, const std::string &input) {
    T n;
    bool valid_input = static_cast<bool>(std::istringstream(input) >> n);
    *target = n;
    return valid_input;
}
```

Comment: `typename V = typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value>::type>` is an anti-pattern; it only works because the two different overloads have a different number of template arguments.  Use `typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value, bool>::type = true>`, it is more robust.

Comment: `typename U = std::underlying_type_t<T>` would be hard error before C++20 though :-/

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I have taken the condition as it was in OP class helper. I didn't know that rule add the few times, I have used `enable_if`, I have used some examples.